# Application crash calling exported delphi function from C++

Tags: function, delphi, call

I have a .DLL compiled in Delphi 7 that exports a function.  I am trying to call that function from C++.

```pascal
procedure SystemReload(lpMessage: PAnsiChar; dwIcon: byte; dwColor: byte);
var
dwMessage: cardinal;
procedure SystemReload_Real(lpMessage: PAnsiChar); assembler;
asm
...
end;
begin
dwMessage := $00415B30;
ShowGameMessage_Real(lpMessage);
end;

exports SystemReload name 'SystemReload';

begin
end.
```

And then the C++ code I am using to call the function:

```cpp
int ShowGameMessage(char* Message, BYTE Icon, BYTE Color)
{
    int ret;

    if (exist("SysReload.dll"))
    {
        HMODULE hLib = LoadLibrary("SysReload.dll");

        if (hLib)
        {

            typedef int(__stdcall *SGMessage)(char*, BYTE, BYTE);

            SGMessage ShowGameMessage = (SGMessage)GetProcAddress(hLib, "SystemReload");

            ret = (*ShowGameMessage)(Message, Icon, Color);

        } else { FreeLibrary(hLib); }

        FreeLibrary(hLib);

    }

    return ret;
}
```

The C++ code is crashing when calling the exported Delphi function.

How do I do things right without crashing the application?

Comment: `if (exist("SysReload.dll"))` seems like a bad idea. Let `LoadLibrary` search for the DLL. If it can't be found, `hLib` will be `NULL`. Loading and unloading a DLL just to call one function seems expensive. Do that too frequently and you can expect trouble. Finally, `ret` is not initialized in case the function fails. If you would enable and heed compiler warnings, the compiler would let you know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not specifying a calling convention in your Delphi code. The default calling convention in Delphi is `register` (which is known as `__fastcall` in C++Builder, and is not supported by any other C++ compiler). Your C++ code is using `__stdcall` for the imported function (the default calling convention in C++ is usually `__cdecl`). Mixing calling conventions is undefined behavior, and can lead to all kinds of problems, including crashes. You need to specify the same calling convention in both languages. In this case, you should use `stdcall` in your Delphi code to match your use of `__stdcall` in your C++ code:

```pascal
procedure SystemReload(lpMessage: PAnsiChar; dwIcon: byte; dwColor: byte); stdcall;
```

Also, your Delphi code is declaring the exported function as a `procedure`, which means it has no return value. But your C++ code is declaring the imported function as having an `int` return type. You should change your C++ code to use `void` to match your use of `procedure` in your Delphi code:

```cpp
typedef void (__stdcall *SGMessage)(char*, BYTE, BYTE);
```

Also, on an unrelated note, your C++ code is calling `FreeLibrary()` twice if `LoadLibrary()` fails. You should not be calling `FreeLibrary()` at all if `LoadLibrary()` fails. Call it only once if `LoadLibrary()` succeeds. You should move your call to `FreeLibrary()` to inside your `if (hLib)` block:

```cpp
void ShowGameMessage(char* Message, BYTE Icon, BYTE Color)
{
    HMODULE hLib = LoadLibrary("SysReload.dll");
    if (hLib)
    {
        typedef void (__stdcall *SGMessage)(char*, BYTE, BYTE);
        SGMessage ShowGameMessage = (SGMessage) GetProcAddress(hLib, "SystemReload");
        if (ShowGameMessage)
            (*ShowGameMessage)(Message, Icon, Color);
        FreeLibrary(hLib);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Delphi export does not look like it is `__stdcall`.

So either declare it as `__fastcall` if you are using C++Builder, or as `stdcall` in the DLL. Since it is a DLL export, `stdcall` is probably the better option.

If you don't use C++Builder, but another C++, then `__fastcall` is not an option, because then, your `__fastcall` is not compatible with Delphi's default `register` calling convention. Better to declare the DLL function as `stdcall` (or `cdecl`, although for DLLs, `stdcall` is more usual).

FWIW, using the default `register` calling convention for a DLL export is a no-no for the reasons layed out above.

More info: [DLL dos and don'ts -- Calling convention](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html#conventions).

Comment: No evidence that C++ Builder is in use here

Comment: @David: you're right. I just assumed it because of the Delphi DLL.